# Error after running build() to create R package in RStudio

Tags: windows, r, rstudio

I am trying to build an R package using RStudio on Windows 8 Pro. When I attempt to build the package by running `build()` I get the error:

```
"C:/Program Files/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD build "H:\File Assembly\FileAssembler"  \
--no-manual --no-resave-data 

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I already have `MiKTEX` installed and I have checked this by:

```
Sys.which("pdflatex") 
                                                        pdflatex
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MIKTEX~1.9\\miktex\\bin\\pdflatex.exe"
```

The R version I am using is: `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"`

Loading library(devtools) and running find_rtools(T) gives:

```
find_rtools(T)  
Scanning path...
ls : c:\Rtools\bin\ls.exe 
gcc: c:\Rtools\GCC-46~1.3\bin\gcc.exe 
VERSION.txt
Rtools version 3.1.0.1942 
Version: 3.1 
[1] TRUE
```

In addition, the path for `rtools` exes are:

```
Sys.which("ls.exe")
                   ls.exe 
"c:\\Rtools\\bin\\ls.exe" 

Sys.which("gcc.exe")
                               gcc.exe 
"c:\\Rtools\\GCC-46~1.3\\bin\\gcc.exe"
```

And checking the path in R:

```
Sys.getenv('PATH')
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.2\\bin\\x64;c:\\Rtools\\bin;c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin;……other paths…………;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\"
```

I would really appreciate help with identifying what I have missed out.

Comment: Did you tried to put double dashes in you PATH. Windows sometimes can be a pain with that. C://Program Files//R/R-30~1.2//bin//x64//R" --vanilla CMD build "H://File Assembly//FileAssembler"

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: Thanks Tarec. Its now edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common error caused by a space in the install location path (C:\Program Files).  The solution, and the official R recommendation is that you never install R in a location with spaces in it on Windows if you want to be able to install packages from source.

from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f:

> If you want to be able to build packages from sources, we recommend
>   that you choose an installation path not containing spaces.

Comment: That works. I have changed the installation location path from C:\Program Files\.... to C:\... and I can now run R on the command prompt. Therefore, I should now not experience the error while trying to build a package. @RyanHorrisberger

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Took some time to find that Rcmd.exe was removed by the Kaspersky antivirus.

once I detected that it was easy to fix.

good luck

Offer

Comment: I have Rcmd.exe in my C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64 so I guess that might not be the issue in my case. @Offer